# How to compare the content of a local folder with Amazon S3?

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created a script to upload the files on a S3 bucket, and I got a timeout error, so I am not sure if all the files are on the bucket. I have created another function for checking the differences, but it seems not to work because of the listing from the local folder:

- If I do a find like [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-compare-the-content-of-two-or-more-directories-automatically/), `find $FOLDER -type f | cut -d/ -f2- | sort`, I get the whole path, like `/home/sop/path/to/folder/...`. It seems that `cut -d/ -f2-` does nothing...
- If I do a `ls -LR` I am not getting a list, for being able to compare it with the `aws s3api list-objects ...` result

Comment: how about `aws s3 sync`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) has a useful `aws s3 sync` command that can replicate files from a local directory to an Amazon S3 bucket (or vice versa, or between buckets).

It will only copy new/changed files, so it's a great way to make sure files have been uploaded.

See: [AWS CLI S3 sync command documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question: how to find out differences between a local folder and an S3 folder.

Comment: could use --dryrun which will show you the differences without changing anything